# why does it jump to another line?

Tags: css, layout, word-wrap

hereis the link: http://eec.github.com/book/

The pictures jump to the second line after 2 picture is showed up.

I know float:left could solve the problem instantly, but I just don't understand why the pictures are arranged like this?

Who can tell me why? Thanks ahead!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next 6 links (after the first 2) don't have whitespace between them, so they can't wrap.

If it helps, images behave as letters in words, so these 6 images basically are in the same "word". The browser doesn't break inside words.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer is short and sharp! I feel no confusing any more.

Answer (score 0):

because there is whitespace after the first and second `a`.

**Your current:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sotiris/Qwk4M

**Fixed:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sotiris/Qwk4M/1/